# Does the use of locks in a thread slow down other threads that don't use locks?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gcc, g++

If I have a thread that frequently uses locks, will it slow down other threads that don't use locks (e.g., because of global lock behavior in the CPU etc).

Comment: Are you speaking of any particular programming language? Any particular OS? Any particular libraries or tool chain?

Comment: C++ using standard library, compiled using g++, run on Linux

Answer (score 1):

No.  Locks simply consist of a system-call.  In C/C++ there is no interpreter-overhead to worry about, no "global interpreter lock" and so on.

*Waiting on a lock* of course does slow things down, and you should carefully plan the design of your application to minimize the chances of a thread requesting a lock and having to wait to get it.  The worst-case scenario is when you divide your application into multiple threads but they're all obliged to wait for something and are thereby effectively serialized.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread acquires a lock, other threads can acquire that same lock until it is released by the thread that acquired it first. While the other threads are waiting for the lock to be released, they will enter idle-mode, meaning they will stop and waiting for the lock to be released. That is why it is a good practice to release locks as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: I believe you meant to say "cannot acquire."

Comment: I was asking about the behavior of threads that don't use locks, not threads that may block on the lock in question.